# How does implementing any django apps into my own project works?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

help needed for general advice with the example on how to implement django apps.

I am trying to implement django app called django-simple-polls.

After installing the app with...

> pip install ...

...adding the app in INSTALLED APPS

...the server still runs...

...migrations runs with no problem...

...being able to create basic poll from the admin...

questions starts here as I do not know how can I see the poll on the server:

1)

> urlpatterns = [
>      ...
>     url(r'^poll/', include('poll.urls')),
>   ]

I am guessing polls app is installed somewhere within django so I do not have to create any additional folder/file in my project. Do I need to import a library to use the include() function? It also mean I need to run polls only in that certain url? That means 'poll.urls' already exist?

2)

Add this tags in your template file to show the poll:

> {% load poll_tags %}
>   ...
>   {% poll %}`

Again my guess is just to create any template folder and put as base the code above. What does "..." mean?. Where do I put the above code? How do I call that HTML file?

Is that pretty much the only way of building apps into a project?

Thanks

ps. At the moment when visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/poll

> ^poll/
>
> ^admin/
>
> ^news/index/ [name='index']
>
> ^news/post/ [name='view_post']
>
> ^news/view/category [name='view_category']
>
> The current path, poll, didn't match any of these.

But there is path called poll. :)

Following the guidance: https://github.com/applecat/django-simple-poll/blob/master/README.md

I have created the following basic template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Polls</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

        {% load poll_tags %}
        ...
        {% poll %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I am unable to render the surveys created in the admin onto the website.

Answer (score 0):

> questions starts here as I do not know how can I see the poll on the server

Answer: Make sure you change your URL mapping for your poll's urls.py.

> urlpatterns = [ ... url(r'^poll/', include('poll.urls')), ]

This should be added to your project's urls.py

> Again my guess is just to create any template folder and put as base the code above. What does "..." mean?. Where do I put the above code? How do I call that HTML file?

If you've set your templates folder in your settings.py you can create another folder named poll then you put your templates there. Then on your views you do.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'poll/yourtemplatename.html')
```

Comment: 'Make sure you change your URL mapping for your poll's urls.py.' -> done; 'Then on your views you do.' -> which view? Github guidance for this package does not mention about anything like that. I do not have any 'django-simple-pool' app folders build into my project. It seems like internal job of so called django magic? :)